# TabCard event when a user has the intent to change tab

Tags: vb.net, events, tabs, tabcontrol

Probably a simple one but a cannot figure out the correct event:

I  have a vb.net `WinForm` with a `TabControl`. On every `TabPage`, the user can enter/modify some data and then (hopefully) save it.

To keep things clean, I want to check, if there is unsaved data, when a user changes tabs (and delete it, if not saved).

I am looking for the best event of the TabCard to do so. There is `TabControl1.Selecting`, `.SelectedIndexChanged` and `.Selected` which look promising but they all fire *AFTER* the Tab changed.
If the user wants to return to save the data, i need to figure out where he came from and show that `TabPage` again. Also the event would the fire again - Not practicable.

In Conlusion: I am looking for a `TabControl` Event, that fires after the user clicked another tabcard but before the card actually changes...
Or a better idea to solve this isse another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Selecting event.  If you don't want to change the tab page, you can cancel the event.

```
'Here's an example class with a tabControl
Public Class Form1

    'this variable stores the currently selected tab
    Private activeTab As TabPage

    'this initializes the activeTab variable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        activeTab = TabControl1.SelectedTab
    End Sub

    'This checks to see if the tab should change or not
    Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting

        If (MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Return to {0} tab?", activeTab.Name), "TabControl", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            activeTab = e.TabPage
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben! Exactly what i was looking for!